# How to add separator between items in a Spark List control

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

I have a s:List where I've defined my own itemRenderer, and would like to insert a horizontal line separating items, similar to the way the mx:LinkBar works.  I don't want to have a line at the top or bottom of the list, so I can't just include an upper or lower border in the itemRenderer. I was hoping the itemRenderer could be made aware of its index in the list, but I don't see how.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If question is still actual, you can find a solution here: http://riatiger.com/blog/2012/06/sparklist-with-separators/

Answer (score 2):

*" I was hoping the itemRenderer could be made aware of its index in the list, but I don't see how. Is there a way to do this?"*

If your itemRenderer implements the IDropInListItemRenderer interface, you can just access the rowIndex property of the listData object.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution I've found to this is to put a gap between the items and let a background Rect (or something) show through between the items.  To do this on List you can just reskin it and customize the VerticalLayout to have a gap.

Comment: Hi James.  Great talk at DevNexus btw.  The problem is that I don't want the separator to be the full width of the list.  My hacked solution was to add the following above the label in the itemRenderer:

<s:VGroup width="100%" horizontalAlign="center" includeInLayout="{!isTop}">
<mx:Canvas width="80%" height="1" backgroundColor="gray" /> 
</s:VGroup>  

Where isTop is detected as:

isTop = this.itemIndex == 0;

Does this make sense?  Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: That works.  With the suggestion I made you could size the background Rect to be the width that you want the separator to be.

Also instead of using a heavy Canvas to draw the line it's better to use the FXG primitives (Rect, Line, etc).